# Are there any schools of Hinduism which hold that one can be a non-theist and still get Moksha?

Tags: philosophy, moksha, shad-darshana, atheism, ishwara

Are there any schools or belief systems in Hinduism where belief in Ishvara, (or any deities for that matter) is not a necessity for attaining Liberation?

Answer (score 1):

Advaita Vedanta is a school which says that only non-theists can attain Moksha. Only Jnana Yoga can take a person to Moksha. Theists can never attain moksha.

**Attitude to Saguna Brahman**

Saguna Brahman is Brahman conceived of as the Creator, Preserver and Destroyer of the Universe corresponding to Isvara. Advaita Vedanta, however, considers Nirguna Brahman as the only Reality. So what does Shankara think of Saguna Brahman? Shankara writes the following in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya:

> 'Hence in sentences of this kind, **the formless Brahman alone, just as
> It is spoken of by the texts themselves, has to be accepted.** But the
> other texts, speaking of Brahman with form, have injunctions about
> meditations as their main objectives. So long as they do not lead to
> some contradiction, their apparent meanings should be accepted. But
> when they involve a contradiction, the principle to be followed for
> deciding one or the other is that, those that have formless Brahman as
> their main purport are more authoritative than the others which have
> not that as their main purport. It is according to this that one is
> driven to the conclusion that Brahman is formless and not its
> opposite, though texts having both the purports are in evidence.'

**Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya III.II.14**

**Only Jnana Yoga can lead to Moksha**

No Yoga other than Jnana Yoga will suffice in attaining moksha.

> All this is erroneous. **Sruti clearly teaches that no road other than
> knowledge leads to moksha.** Vide: "Knowing Him alone one conquers
> death: no other road is available for going there" (Svetasvatara
> Upanishad 3.8). Further, 6.20 (ibid) teaches that the non-knower's
> achievement of moksha is as impossible as the folding up of the sky
> like a hide. Puranas, too, teach that moksha is won through knowledge.

**Sankaracharya Gita bhasya 18.66.6 translated by A. G. Krishna Warrier**

Sri Sankaracharya’s settled conclusion is that the worship of Saguna Brahman prepares a person for Jnana Yoga. It doesn’t directly lead to the attainment of Advaita moksha. Modern masters like Sri Ramakrishna, Swami Vivekananda and Sri Ramana Maharshi disagree.

Comment: I have heard some lectures of some orthodox shankaracharyas of the current age and honestly they happen to lay far more emphasis on Bhakti than Jnana path

Comment: I only quoted Adi Shankaracharya. I don't know what later Shankaracharyas said.

Answer (score 0):

### Shankhya

> **Arguments against Ishvara's existence**
>
> According to Sinha, the following arguments were given by Samkhya philosophers against the
> idea of an eternal, self-caused, creator God:[153]
>
> 1. If the existence of karma is assumed, the proposition of God as a moral governor of the universe is unnecessary. For, if God enforces
>    the consequences of actions then he can do so without karma. If
>    however, he is assumed to be within the law of karma, then karma
>    itself would be the giver of consequences and there would be no need
>    of a God.
> 2. Even if karma is denied, God still cannot be the enforcer of consequences. Because the motives of an enforcer God would be either
>    egoistic or altruistic. Now, God's motives cannot be assumed to be
>    altruistic because an altruistic God would not create a world so full
>    of suffering. If his motives are assumed to be egoistic, then God must
>    be thought to have desire, as agency or authority cannot be
>    established in the absence of desire. However, assuming that God has
>    desire would contradict God's eternal freedom which necessitates no
>    compulsion in actions. Moreover, desire, according to Samkhya, is an
>    attribute of prakṛti and cannot be thought to grow in God. The
>    testimony of the Vedas, according to Samkhya, also confirms this
>    notion.
> 3. Despite arguments to the contrary, if God is still assumed to contain unfulfilled desires, this would cause him to suffer pain and
>    other similar human experiences. Such a worldly God would be no better
>    than Samkhya's notion of higher self.
> 4. Furthermore, there is no proof of the existence of God. He is not the object of perception, there exists no general proposition that can
>    prove him by inference and the testimony of the Vedas speak of prakṛti
>    as the origin of the world, not God.
>
> Therefore, Samkhya maintained that the various cosmological,
> ontological and teleological arguments could not prove God.

Sinha, Nandlal (2012), The Samkhya Philosophy, New Delhi: Hard Press, ISBN 978-1407698915

> 24. Icvara (the Supreme Ruler) is a special Purusa, untouched by misery, the results of actions, or desires.
>
> **We must again remember that this Patanjali Yoga Philosophy is based**
> **upon that of the Sankhyas, only that in the latter there is no place**
> **for God**, while with the Yogis God has a place. The Yogis, however,
> avoid many ideas about God, such as creating. God as the Creator of
> the Universe is not meant by the Icvara of the Yogis, although,
> according to the Vedas, Icvara is the Creator of the universe. Seeing
> that the universe is harmonious, it must be the manifestation of one
> will. The Yogis and Sankhyas both avoid the question of creation. **The**
> **Yogis want to establish a God, but carefully avoid this question, they**
> **do not raise it at all. Yet you will find that they arrive at God in a**
> **peculiar fashion of their own.**

Vivekananda, Swami. Raja yoga or conquering the internal nature. Read Books Ltd, 2020. pp 103.

### Nyaya

> Early Naiyyayikas wrote very little about Ishvara (literally, the
> Supreme Soul). Evidence available so far suggests that early Nyāya
> scholars were non-theistic or atheists.[55][56] Later, and over time,
> Nyāya scholars tried to apply some of their epistemological insights
> and methodology to the question: does God exist? Some offered
> arguments against and some in favor.[23]
>
> Arguments that God does not exist
>
> In Nyāya Sūtra's Book 4, Chapter 1, verses 19–21, postulates God
> exists, states a consequence, then presents contrary evidence, and
> from contradiction concludes that the postulate must be invalid.[57]
>
> **The Lord is the cause, since we see that human action lacks results.**
>
> **This is not so since, as a matter of fact, no result is accomplished
> without human action.**
>
> **Since this is efficacious, the reason lacks force.**
>
> — Nyaya Sutra, IV.1.19 - IV.1.21 [57]
>
> A literal interpretation of the three verses suggests that Nyāya
> school rejected the need for a God for the efficacy of human activity.
> Since human action and results do not require assumption or need of
> the existence of God, sutra IV.1.21 is seen as a criticism of the
> "existence of God and theism postulate".[57]

Original Sanskrit: Nyayasutra, Anandashram Sanskrit Granthvali, pages 290-292;
English translation: Francis X. Clooney (2010), Hindu God, Christian God: How Reason Helps Break Down the Boundaries, Oxford University Press, ISBN 978-0-19-973872-4, page 37

### Advaita Vedanta

> This gives room in Advaita Vedanta to show the nature of Ishvara as
> both the material and instrumental cause of this universe and the
> individual who is limited in his own capacities as unreal and declare
> that there is oneness between the two having negated the qualities.
> This establishes Ishvara as 'saguṇa' or with attributes from the
> empirical existence and 'nirguṇa' from the absolute sense. This
> oneness is accepted only at the level of 'mukti' or ultimate
> realization and not at the 'vyavahara' or empirical level. At the
> absolute level there is no otherness nor distinction between Jiva
> (living being) and Ishvara, and any attempts to distinguish the two is
> a false idea, one based on wrong knowledge, according to Advaita
> Vedanta.[51]
>
> **ईश्वरः अहम्**
>
> **Ishvara, I am.**
>
> — *Adi Shankara, Upadesasahasri 2.3.1, 2.10.8[19]*
>
> Other Advaitin Hindu texts resonate with the monist views of Adi
> Shankara.

*NB: Ishvara is not considered an independent entity of self.*

Comment: What are the above school's views on liberation and do they hold that it can be attained without surrendering to any concept of Ishvara?

Comment: Blogs and Wikipedia are not a valid source. You have to cite authoritative texts directly, as you have done in the case of Vedanta citing Upadeshasahashri.

Comment: don't copy from Wikipedia. Please add original sources for the Nyaya and Samkhya views.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay Wiki links have been replaced by Authors/Philosophers, where interpretation of the texts have been considered from different POVs.

Comment: @Chatuskoti To the best of my knowledge, liberation is ONLY attained in all schools after the knowledge of self has been attained, in all schools, but some schools require devotion to Ishvara to be enforced to free the jiva from karma before he knows self. In other schools, usually, the Self (Atman) -  (without/or including as self) Ishvara is also considered valid.

Comment: @User29449 thank you. Please add the samkhya sutra verse number.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay I'm not sure if any verse of *ShankhyaKarika* talks about *Ishvara*. Further, I've added N. Sinha and Swami Vivekananda, who interpret it *Ishvara-less* in their texts.